# Is it safe to put email addreses in PHP variables against email harvesters?

Tags: php, email

Is it safe to use either of these lines without having the emails being picked up by email harvesters?

```
My email: <a href="mailto:<?php echo 'testing@example.com'; ?>"><?php echo 'testing@example.com'; ?></a>
```

or this one *with* variables

```
<?php $email = 'testing@example.com'; ?>
My email: <a href="mailto:<?php echo $email; ?>"><?php echo $email; ?></a>
```

or does it even matter for as long as it's generated by PHP then it's safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those will provide no protection at all. PHP is run on the server side. It will generate an HTML document and send it to the client. From the perspective of a bot or a user this is exactly the same as if you had just put the email address in a normal HTML document:

```
My email: <a href="mailto:testing@example.com">testing@example.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your both example with give the same HTML output

```
My email: <a href="mailto:testing@example.com">testing@example.com</a>
```

and **YES** it is vulnerable to crawler.

If email address is such of such importance.

Create a contact form, add some captcha and send the form details through PHP, without exposing the email address anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of these will be safe -- the bots crawl the generated HTML served, so the PHP is out of the equation by then and has already spit out the email address.

Your best bet for a similar solution would be to use JavaScript to inject the email address after the DOM has loaded.  Most bots and spiders cruise without JavaScript, and will see the email-free HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The way to understand what you're asking is: what will the page look like when it is rendered to a client that requests it? An email harvester requests your page and parses it looking for email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect addresses from crawlers, use some form of contact form that sends mail to you without exposing your email address at all.

If you want to provide your address to readers but not to crawlers, T.J. Schuck's suggestion of injecting it via JavaScript after the page loads makes sense, but be sure that you're constructing it from several pieces in the JS code - an intact address in the script source may still be picked up.